# fold left to convert a List of List into a string

Tags: scala

I want convert a list of list to string with a deliminator using fold left

I am trying to create a String but it has extra deliminator

```
 trait Msg {

    def toCustString(flag:Boolean): String
  }

  trait Ele[T] extends Msg {

    val value: T

    override def toCustString(flag:Boolean): String = s"${value}"

  }

  trait Grp extends Msg {

    val list: Seq[Msg]

    override def toCustString(flag: Boolean = false): String = {

      val sep = if (flag) "\n" else "!"
      test((builder: StringBuilder, elem: Msg) => builder.append(s"$sep${elem.toCustString(false)}$sep"))

    }

    def test(acc: (StringBuilder, Msg) => StringBuilder): String = {
      list.foldLeft(StringBuilder.newBuilder)(acc).toString()
    }


  }

case class MyMessage(list:Seq[Msg]) extends Grp
case class TypeA(value: Int) extends Ele[Int]
case class TypeB(value: String) extends Ele[String]
case class TypeC(value: Float) extends Ele[Float]
case class MyGrp (list:Seq[Msg]) extends Grp

object Demo extends App{
  val grp1 = MyGrp(Seq(TypeA(2)))
  val grp2 = MyGrp(Seq(TypeB("ABC"), TypeC(20)))
  val s=MyGrp(Seq(grp1,grp2))
  val m = MyMessage(Seq(TypeA(2),s)).toCustString(false)
  print(m)

}
```

**Updated**

**My output** is !2!!!!2!!!!ABC!!20.0!!!

**Expected** 2!2!ABC!20.0!

Comment: can anyone please explain the reason for downvote.Any improvements

Comment: on my computer this code already returns expected result

Comment: @mkUltra sry for mistake I have updated the question.My expected output is `2!2!ABC!20.0!`

Comment: I am not sure why you would expect that result. Looking at your `toCustString` definition, it's obvious that the result will always start with a separator.

Comment: Are you sure that expected result is "2!2!ABC!20.0!" and not "2!2!ABC!20.0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `foldLeft` for this. If I am guessing correctly what you are trying to do from your "expected result" (it's an awful way to ask a question, btw), something like this should work (you don't seem to be using `flag` anywhere, so I dropped it):

```
  trait Grp extends Msg {
    def toCustString: String = list.map(_.toCustString).mkString("!")
  }
```

If the extra separator at the end wasn't a typo, then, the best way to tuck it on is, just do it explicitly: `val m = MyMessage(Seq(TypeA(2),s)).toCustString + "!"`

Comment: I need flag for a reason

Comment: I need flag for a reason my delamination depends on condition

Comment: that's fine, you can have the flag if you want. It's just in your example, it wasn't used, so I omitted it.

Comment: Any other way to concatenate ! at end ..`val m = MyMessage(Seq(TypeA(2),s)).toCustString + "!"`

Comment: Sure. Plenty of them. `s"${MyMessage(Seq(TypeA(2),s)).toCustString}!"`, `"%s!".format(MyMessage(Seq(TypeA(2),s)).toCustString)`, `"%s%s".format(MyMessage(Seq(TypeA(2),s)).toCustString, "!")` .. etc.

Comment: Thks for ur advise .Can we abstract to concatenate !  in `toCustString` as I want te logic to be all there inside trait

Comment: I tried this   `val sep ='"!" 
list.map(_.toCustString(false)).foldLeft(new StringBuilder) { (sb, sep) => sb append sep }.toString` but it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

Usually to convert list items to string with a separator I use mkString:

```
List("", "B", "C").mkString(",")
```

We can do the same things with foldLeft in this way:

```
List("", "B", "C").foldLeft(List[String]())((acc, item) =>
   if (acc.isEmpty) acc :+ item else acc :+ "," :+ item
).mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stringutils.join with stream.